# installing jupyter notebook on an Amazon AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I have some AWS server that I am trying to install jupyter notebook on.

I do the following steps:

Go to my home directory and make a virtual environment using

```
python3.6 -m venv env
```

Activate the venv

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Install Jupyter

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

python -m pip install jupyter
```

Run jupyter notebook

```
jupyter notebook
```

Everything seems to work until I run `jupyter notebook`.

I get the following error:

```
(env) root@ip-172-51-23-114:/home/USER# jupyter notebook --allow-root
[I 21:14:53.193 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/USER
[I 21:14:53.193 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 21:14:53.193 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=4a83abb3edf214bff5796dae4cf0ed756b1d99972e4134e7
[I 21:14:53.193 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=4a83abb3edf214bff5796dae4cf0ed756b1d99972e4134e7
[I 21:14:53.193 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 21:14:53.198 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-25435-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=4a83abb3edf214bff5796dae4cf0ed756b1d99972e4134e7
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=4a83abb3edf214bff5796dae4cf0ed756b1d99972e4134e7
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
Couldn't find a suitable web browser!
Set the BROWSER environment variable to your desired browser.
Warning: program returned non-zero exit code #1
WARNING: You don't seem to have any mimeinfo.cache files.
Try running the update-desktop-database command. If you
don't have this command you should install the
desktop-file-utils package. This package is available from
http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/desktop-file-utils/
Can't call method "get_value" on an undefined value at /usr/bin/mimeopen line 159.
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: x-www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: firefox: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: iceweasel: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: seamonkey: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: mozilla: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: epiphany: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: konqueror: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: google-chrome: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-25435-open.html'
```

I install python and jupter notebook through the terminal in RStudio.

Should I try to install chrome or another web browser on the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the networking permissions you've configured, you can try connecting to the Jupyter notebook on your EC2 instance with the domain followed by the port. For example,

`https://<ec2-address>:<port>`

For an example instance in the `us-west-2` region:

`https://ec2-52-39-239-66.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8888/`

It will likely either prompt you for a token in the EC2 auth window, or you can simply append it to the end of the above URL:

`https://ec2-52-39-239-66.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8888/?token=4a83abb3edf214bff5796dae4cf0ed756b1d99972e4134e7`

Comment: Thanks! I did not see your comment earlier. I spent some time following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@josemarcialportilla/getting-spark-python-and-jupyter-notebook-running-on-amazon-ec2-dec599e1c297 - I managed to get the Jupyter up and running but I get an error `404 : Not Found You are requesting a page that does not exist!` - This is for my `https://ec2-xxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8888/tree` link. So the tree doesn't diplay anything (but I get a Jupyter logo on the top left) Even using `https://52.90.50.85:8888/tree` takes me to the error 404 page.

Comment: Reading briefly online this could be due to hidden folders. I have some jupyter files saved as `.jupyter` etc.

Comment: Check out this github issue: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2382